# Function return type is somehow not considered to be a part of the immediate context for SFINAE purposes?

Tags: c++, sfinae

I feel I'm missing something painfully obvious.

<kbd>[run on gcc.godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:11,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:11,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:11,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:11),source:%27%23include+%3Ctype_traits%3E%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T,+typename+...P%3E%0Astruct+construct%0A%7B%0A++++decltype(T(std::declval%3CP%3E()...))+foo()%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T%3E%0Aconcept+int_constructible+%3D+requires%0A%7B%0A++++construct%3CT,+int%3E%7B%7D.foo()%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Astruct+A+%7B%7D%3B%0Astatic_assert(!!int_constructible%3CA%3E)%3B%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:53.89033942558748,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang1400,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-Wall+-Wextra+-pedantic-errors%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+14.0.0+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:100,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+12.1%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%270%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+clang+14.0.0+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:46.10966057441255,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)</kbd>

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename ...P>
struct construct
{
    decltype(T(std::declval<P>()...)) foo();
};

template <typename T>
concept int_constructible = requires
{
    construct<T, int>{}.foo();
};

struct A {};
static_assert(!int_constructible<A>);
```

I expect this to compile, but it causes a hard error not caught by SFINAE, on both GCC, Clang, and MSVC.

```
<source>:6:14: error: no matching conversion for functional-style cast from 'int' to 'A'
    decltype(T(std::declval<P>()...)) foo();
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

What am I missing? The return type of `foo()` looks like a part of the immediate context to me.

Comment: The instantiation of `construct` instantiates the declaration of `foo` which is a hard error.

Comment: if foo was a function template its return type would be considered for SFINAE

Comment: You might place the restriction on the class: `template <typename T, typename ...P> requires(std::is_constructible_v<T, P...>) struct construct {/**/}`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Mhm. But my actual code targets C++14, so I'll have to settle for a dummy template parameter on `foo`.

Comment: or an extra parameter on `construct` (with some indirection) to be SFINAE friendly: [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/GKn4GKj57).